# Call a function every time a specific piece of text is inserted

Tags: hooks

I'm wondering whether there is an already existing mechanism of executing a function every time a specific piece of text is inserted.

For example, I would like to call `company-bibtex` whenever I enter `\cite{` in a `latex-mode`-buffer.

Of course I can always just rebind `{` and then check if the text before point is `\cite`, but I wondered whether there was already something existing that I could hook into for something like that?

Comment: [Abbrevs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Abbrevs.html) perhaps?

Comment: AFAIK `company-bibtex` should already do that.  Maybe you need to configure the number of chars needed after the brace before it auto-pops up to 0?